# How change select from Select box plugin using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I can't get why I can't dot this - it should be simple.

If some error div exists - I want to change Select box styling, but I'm failing to do this.

Here is how I set Select Box in my CSS file:

```
.selectBox-options{
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(98,141, 40);
border-left: 1px solid rgb(98,141, 40);
border-right: 1px solid rgb(98,141, 40);
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Then if there is div, which called field_with_errors - I should change styling.

Here is code:

```
   if($('.field_with_errors').is(':visible')){
        alert('aaa')
        $('.selectBox-options').css({"-moz-box-shadow":"0 0 3px 3px rgba(222,162, 162, 0.4)"});
    }
```

Field_with_errors DO appears, because I get alert box.

How I can change border and box-shadow ?

Answer (score 0):

use this for changing.

```
$('.selectBox-options').css("-moz-box-shadow","0 0 3px 3px rgba(222,162, 162, 0.4)");
```

beacause sytax for changing css is

```
$('#id').css('property','value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$('.selectBox-options').css({"-moz-box-shadow":"0 0 3px 3px rgba(222,162, 162, 0.4)",
                            "-webkit-box-shadow":"0 0 3px 3px rgba(222,162, 162, 0.4)",
                             "box-shadow":"0 0 3px 3px rgba(222,162, 162, 0.4)",
                            });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geems/1/)

Comment: You can look at the problem using firebug. If it is an error that relate with javascript, you can see an error on firebug.console or chrome console. Or if it is an error that relate with CSS, you can see using element inspect.

Comment: No errors in Firebug or Google console. Tried to inspect, but didn't see, that rule from jquery is overrided.

Comment: Is there an url your project on web ?

Comment: I will put some changes and then send you a link.

Comment: http://91.228.126.168:3000 - put some url in website url field and doesn't select anything to show errors

Comment: MID:there is an error in error console saying `[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector`.
line-27 of jquery.cycle.all.latest.js

Comment: There is slider on one page - I don't think that it is causing error. Ok, I will delete piece of code to make sure. Try again.

Comment: No, but some people could be testing my project and it will be bad if they won't saw project)

Comment: @MID I looked at your site. I could not see any problem your login screen. If there is no info, it shows error with red border around input.

Comment: I just wanted to change Select box if user chose 'please select option'

Comment: I just left it until (if) someone tell me to do that.

Comment: @MID The url that you have given before is not running. Can you give the url of your site again?